# Why should I need to keep this line %%timeit -n 100 as the first line of the file in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I've typed this comment line before **%%timeit -n 100** line and I've got an error!

```
# using parallel programming
%%timeit -n 100  
summary = 0

for item in s:
    summary += item
```

**Output:**

> UsageError: Line magic function `%%timeit` not found.

Again, if I keep this line as the first executable line of the python file, then it's OK.
Just like this:

```
%%timeit -n 100   
summary = 0
# using parallel programming
for item in s:
    summary += item
```

**Output:**

> 2.47 ms ± 239 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100
> loops each)

***Why does this happen? Why should it be kept as the first line?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a Jupyter Notebook ?

%%timeit will evaluate the runtime of the entire cell, whereas %timeit will only evaluate runtime for the current line. If you add a comment first, %%timeit is not applicable anymore, as this magic function is not the first line of the cell anymore.

Whenever you want to use a magic function, put it as the first line of the cell.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.Yes, I'm using Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: Anyway, there is no real detailed reason. If you use a %% function, you have to put it before any code. Is this solved your question, set it as the answer so that it's not in the unanswered question list anymore :)